# SQL - Add Date and Time in the error result

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to add the date and time for every thrown SQL error?
Example:

> Msg 8134, Level 16, State 1, Line 97
>   Divide by zero error encountered.

Should be something like

> Msg 8134, Level 16, State 1, Line 97, **04/02/2018**, **12:20**, Divide by zero error encountered.

The only functions I know regarding errors are:
ERROR_LINE,
ERROR_MESSAGE,
ERROR_NUMBER,
ERROR_PROCEDURE,
ERROR_SEVERITY,
ERROR_STATE

Comment: Nope. At least you can't insert that into the error message. Honestly, the date and the message are two different piece of information and as such do not belong in the same piece of data.

Comment: You *know* the date of the error. It's the value of `GetDate()` or `DateTime.Now` wherever you catch and log it. SQL Server's log contains the date for errors severe enough to be written to the log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the code below as a starting point, add the date and time wherever it suits you:

DECLARE @ErrorNumber INT = ERROR_NUMBER();

DECLARE @ErrorLine INT = ERROR_LINE();

DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000) = ERROR_MESSAGE();

DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT = ERROR_SEVERITY();

DECLARE @ErrorState INT = ERROR_STATE();

PRINT 'Actual error number: ' + CAST(@ErrorNumber AS VARCHAR(10));

PRINT 'Actual line number: ' + CAST(@ErrorLine AS VARCHAR(10));

RAISERROR(@ErrorMessage, @ErrorSeverity, @ErrorState);